# Virtual environment for Linux Kernel hacking

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, virtual-machine

This question is to practicing Linux kernel hackers:
Generally, it is best to test/play with linux kernel changes/hacks in a virtualized enviroment.

1. What virtual environment do you use for testing your hacks?
2. How do you make a minimalistic filesystem(with basic utils) to use with the environment. If you are using a readymade filesystem, what is that are you using?
3. Useful heuristics you do with your environment(like installing a new kernel, sharing files etc?

Please provide a step by step procedure to setup the environment, if possible.
A collection of this info doesnt seem available in web.

Thanks.

Comment: QEMU + Buildroot fully automated setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Answer (score 2):

Different people use different set ups, I don't think there is one true answer.

I currently use VirtualBox as Hypervisor with a file system created with Buildroot.

Apart from other VMs (kvm, qemu, vmware etc.) you could also use User Mode Linux to much the same effect if your hacking is in the more "logical" layers of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a Fedora14 VM running in QEMU/KVM on a Fedora14 host for my network driver development.  I use a fairly standard install with the Software Development packages, plus whatever web or networking tools (e.g. wireshark) might be useful for the task.  I typically set up a serial console on the VM and monitor it with minicom on the host - this helps me catch stack traces when I'm chasing a bug.  I usually have my source and editing environment on the host machine with the files on an NFS file system that the VM mounts - this way I don't have to keep copying files to and from the VM.  With the host running the same version kernel, I can compile the driver quickly on the multicore host and test it in the VM.